# How to get the tab id where the chrome extension is opened

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am opening the extension in the new window.
**Background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(msg, sender, response){
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {tabId: tabs[0].id}, function(response) {});
    // creating new window.
    chrome.windows.create({ url: 'popup.html', width: 320, height: 480})
 })
})
```

Before opening new window, the tab ID will be the active tab ID means where i opened the chrome extension(eg: google.com). I am trying to access that tab ID in **popup.js**. Because i want to access the DOM of the page(google.com) where chrome extension is opened. How can i do that? or is there any other way to get the tab ID in the **popup.js**?

Tried other way in **popup.js**

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, function(tabs){
  console.log(tabs)
});
```

Here i am getting all the window tabs in popup.js, but here i do not know that tab ID where extension is opened(google.com)?

Comment: `chrome.windows.create({ url: 'popup.html', width: 320, height: 480})` will create new window right. If i use `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` it is giving the current popup window object not the google.com object.

Comment: Popup is complete new window, it will not be as part of window, where i opened the chrome extension.

Comment: Ah. You can pass the id via url parameter like `url: 'popup.html#' + tab.id` and then extract it in your popup.js. Or you can send a message, but that's more convoluted.

Comment: Thank you that works too. But i solved in other way, Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its actually very simple

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){})
```

Its is giving what are all the active window tabs and accessing other window DOM(google.com)

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{   //tabs[0].id will give the tab id where extension is opened.
    code: 'document'  // any javascript statement
  })
})
```

Comment: Update: This solution doesn't seem to work with manifest v3 because there isn't a "code" parameter in executeScript.  There is a "func" parameter that might be made to work, but adding the parameters to the query string might be a more robust solution.