# Can a chrome extension pop-up know if it is being opened for the first time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs, popup, content-script

I am building an extension where the pop-up is used as a UI interface while the action happens in a content script.

Here's the problem: The pop-up can open and close throughout the lifetime of a tab but its behavior should be different if it is being opened for the first time. For example, it should only execute the content script if being opened for the first time.

**Is there a way for the pop-up to know if it is being opened for the first time on the current tab**?

Comment: You can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) to query the content script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

Send one-time message from pop-up script every time it's opened:

```
const errString = "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.";

chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
    let tabId = tabs[0].id;

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {event: 'popup-ready'}, {}, (response) => {
        let lastError = chrome.runtime.lastError;

        if (lastError && lastError.message == errString) {
             // Content script not in place -> pop-up running for the first time.
             // Run content script...
        } else if (response.event == 'content-ready') {
             // Content script in place -> pop-up not running for the first time.
        }
}
```

In the content script you need to create a handler for the `message` event:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, sender, sendResp) => {
    if (req.event && req.event === 'popup-ready') {
        sendResp({event: 'content-ready'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert when it comes to browser extensions, so someone else may well have a better solution, however, maybe you could store the tab's ID in localStorage or sessionStorage whenever you open the popup in a tab, and then whenever you open the popup you could check if the ID is already found in the local/session storage to know if it's already been opened before?

You might have to perform the check inside the content script (I'm not sure what exactly can be run from the popup itself), but then you can prevent it from running twice if it's been run before.

[You can see how to get a tab's ID here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104972/how-to-get-the-tab-id-where-the-chrome-extension-is-opened)

Comment: The localStorage and sessionStorage objects don't seem to be shared across the different pop-up instances since, according to a [Chromium Issue from 2010](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42599), "every time an `ExtensionHost` is created, it 
creates a `RenderViewHost` with a new session storage namespace id". 
It worked using Chrome's [Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) though, so thank you! Still hoping for something more elegant though.

Comment: That bug is about `sessionStorage` which is per window as it should be. However, `localStorage` is shared across the entire origin - that is between all instances of extension's browser_action popup - just as it should per spec. P.S. that bug is also invalid because the popup's window is recreated each time - this is the way the popup API was implemented.